# Auto Capitilize first two characters in Excel Range

Tags: excel, vba, logic

I am trying to force a specific range of cells in Excel to auto capitalize a specific phrase.

For example: We commonly enter type of aircraft such as Saab, Citation, etc.  I have a VB script to force Proper Case but there are other times that we abbreviate such as DA20, CJ3, etc.

What I would like (if this is even possible) is for the long names (if used) to remain Proper Case however if they type specific phrases, I would like it to ignore the script and allow it as entered OR auto capital the first two characters.

> Diamond or DA20 would be acceptable
>
> Citation or CJ3 would be acceptable

What I don't want is someone that is lazy to type

> citation or cj3
>
> diamond or da20

Is this possible?  I would be willing to create a whitelist of sorts of all the abbreviations if necessary that would be allowed.

I was hoping some sort "IF" statement may work on the VBA script but I am unsure how to write this.

Comment: single words in the cells or phrases of several words??

Comment: The answer to your question is: YES, it is possible.

Comment: Ah, thanks ... I forgot about AutoCorrect.  That will work!

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger auto-updating of certain ranges using the Worksheet Change event. This requires the user to partially enter the desired input (they need to exit the cell for it to trigger) and will auto-fill the remainder. For instance:

```
Public boolChanging As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal rng As Range)
    Dim strAutoFinish As String, iStartPos As Integer

    'Exit unless updates occur when and where you want
    If boolChanging Or rng.Row < 1 Or rng.Column <> 1 Or rng.Columns.Count > 1 Or rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If rng = "" Then Exit Sub 'This needs to be here in case multiple cells are editted

    boolChanging = True
    strAutoFinish = ";DA20;Diamond;CJ3;Citation;..."
    iStartPos = InStr(UCase(strAutoFinish), ";" & UCase(rng))

    If iStartPos > 0 Then
        rng = Mid(strAutoFinish, iStartPos + 1, InStr(iStartPos + 1, strAutoFinish, ";") - iStartPos - 1)
    Else 'Leave this part if you want it to delete invalid entries
        rng = ""
    End If

    boolChanging = False
End Sub
```